# How can I make an Observable Hashset in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Currently I am using an ObservableCollection within a WPF application, the application is an implementation of Conway's Game of life and works well for about 500 cells but after that it begins to slow down significantly. I originally wrote the application using a HashSet but couldn't find any way to bind the cells to a canvas.

Is there a way to get my HashSet to notify its binding object of changes? My Cell class is a simple integer X,Y pair, if the pair exists the cell is alive otherwise dead. The Cell implements INotifyPropertyChanged and overrides GetHashCode and Equals. I couldn't get the cell to display any changes, just the cells present immediately after loading. Is there any way to Bind a Hashset to items on a Canvas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to implement [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx) too, and then it should all work OK. There's another relevant SO answer which [uses freezables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269073/observablecollection-that-also-monitors-changes-on-the-elements-in-collection) to ensure that changes in underlying entities are also handled.

Comment: Hmm, I will take a look at that, INotifyCollectionChanged might just be my missing link, thanks!

Answer (score 15):

I don't know if this will help, but here's a *really* simple implementation of an "observable set" that I made for a personal project. It essentially guards against inserting (or overwriting with) an item that is already in the collection.

If you wanted to you could simply return out of the methods rather than throwing an exception.

```
public class SetCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T> 
{
    protected override void InsertItem(int index, T item)
    {
        if (Contains(item)) throw new ItemExistsException(item);

        base.InsertItem(index, item);
    }

    protected override void SetItem(int index, T item)
    {
        int i = IndexOf(item);
        if (i >= 0 && i != index) throw new ItemExistsException(item);

        base.SetItem(index, item);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very close to what I already have, I use an observablecollection and simply guarantee that all items are unique. In my code rather than through inheritance but hey i'm a wimp ;)

Comment: Yeah I'd say that this is easier than reimplementing HashSet so that it implements INotifyCollectionChanged. All the hard work is already being done by ObservableCollection<T> for you.

Comment: going off of reflector it appears that you would want to only expose the default constructor or implement the others yourself, as the base calls a private `CopyFrom` Method instead of `InsertItem`

Comment: -1 because this isn't really a set, since it (in the code-behind) uses indexes. Sets gain performance because they are object-reference based. In this implementation, the same performance gain wouldn't be achieved. Actually, the performance would be far worse.

Comment: @Mathias Huh? How does this "use indexes"? It uses object references. The call to `IndexOf` will use an object reference to determine if the object is in the set.

Comment: A set defines the behavior, not the implementation. This is a set, but one with O(n) for insert, update, find.

Comment: That's how I would like to do it, but the Add method of Observable collection is not virtual, so it can't be overridden. That means duplicate items can be added.

Answer (score 12):

I've posted a complete ObservableHashSet here that you can use.

https://github.com/BellaCode/Public/tree/master/ObservableHashSet

It is based of reflecting on how ObservableCollection is implemented and provides the same thread-safety re-entrancy checks.

Comment: Its nice, but but to fill the `newItems`, `oldItems` collections you need to perform some really slow operations. I would probably add an option not to fill those at all and only report that something changed by raising the event.

Comment: `int index = this.hashSet.IndexOf(item);` error `Error 1 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<T>' does not contain a definition for 'IndexOf' and no extension method 'IndexOf' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<T>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Too many extraneous dependencies; overengineered. See below for a much simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can steal it from `EntityFramework Core`

https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/main/src/EFCore/ChangeTracking/ObservableHashSet.cs

Lately I extracted the class from EF repo to standalone nuget:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Kebechet.Types.ObservableHashSet