# .NET: Observable + Sortable CollectionView on a Set (custom HasSet<>)

Tags: c#, .net, collections, view, set

I look for a way to observe a collection for changes, without using indices. I know when items are added and removed from the source collection, but the collection is not using indices (it's a custom kind of hashset with notification on add/remove). Items are being populated to the list in a undeterministic order and using indices wouldnt make much sense, so I'm trying to avoid it completely. But Im still going to bind this list to a view, so there will be some ordering of the items eventually. My goal is to have all the ordering in a collectionview.

The question is if there is a way to make a collectionview on a index-less source collection and still get the UI to respond to items being removed and added effectively without having to rebuild the list everytime. I'm not sure if I make any sense here. My goal is to get rid of indices but still benefit from collectionchanged-events and collectionview-ordering. Possible?

**UPDATE**

I've tried to implement a custom ICollectionView such as SetCollectionView(HashSet set) but it won't work for some reason. Not yet anyway.

Another option could perhaps be to implement a custom ReadOnlyObservableCollection-wrapper with some custom ordering on the GetEnumerator. I haven't tested it yet. I would have to sort the list according to the choosen ordering before extracting the index for the NotifyCollectionChanged-event but that should work.

Comment: What defines your order if not an index? A hashset is an explicitly un-ordered data structure.

Comment: if a HashSet is un-ordered then how do you expect to know which item(s) are to be removed Andreas..? and why would you want an Index-Less custom collection anyway..??

Comment: In my case I'm not very interested in the position of items, only if they are part of a collection/set or not. The ordering is up to the presentation and view layer.
When removing items I'm not using RemoveAt(0) but Remove(item).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ObservableHashSet class.

See the question here

[How can I make an Observable Hashset in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526986/how-can-i-make-an-observable-hashset-in-c)

or go directly to the code here:

http://geoffcox.bellacode.com/2011/12/09/observablehashset/

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an index somewhere, because all of the UI binding plumbing is index-based.  You can layer an indexed list over your existing hashset, but it's going to be slow (I can't provide a formal proof, but my gut tells me it would be quite awful, something like O(n)). If you want a quick base collection that you can layer re-ordered UI lists on top of, you might want to look into a balanced sorted tree, rather than a hashset.

Comment: The items in the source collection is not by default comparable to each other, so a sorted tree is not of much use here I guess...