# Observable CollectionViewSource

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am trying to set up a ListBox that gets it's data from a CollectionViewSource. What I want to happen is that when I update the underlying data source the ListBox also updates. My Xaml looks like this...

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="AppTests" ObjectType="{x:Type Application:AppTestProvider}" MethodName="GetAppTests" />
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs" Source="{StaticResource AppTests}">
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Priority" Direction="Ascending" />
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="TestList" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding TestName}" />                    
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

This displays the data fine but if I change the underlying data then the changes don't appear on the grid until I call the `cvs.View.Refresh()` method in the code behind.

How can I make this "observable" so the changes happen automatically?

Note: The reason for using the CVS was to provide sorting to the list based on a property in the underlying objects.

Comment: Use ObservableCollection.

Comment: After posting this I also read that a CollectionViewSource does not observe changes. Is that correct and can that affect what I am doing?

Comment: No, its not true. `CollectionViewSource` listens to Collection changed if underlying source collection implements it.

Comment: @RohitVats, it is true in a sense, that `CollectionViewSource` does not observe changes _on its own_. It does not create notification events, but simply forwards them to UI layer.

Comment: @Nikita - Yeah that's what i wrote in my answer as well - `It propagate INotifyCollectionChanged events if the underlying collection implements it.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To see changes, made to the collection itself (e.g. adding and removing items), the collection should implement `INotifyCollectionChanged` (`ObservableCollection` is the base implementation of this interface). To see changes, made to items in the collection (e.g. modifying a specific property on specific item), your item object should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

CollectionViewSource is a layer between UI and actual collection, which provides some additional control over how the collection is displayed (sorting, filtering, grouping, etc.). It only passes notifications to UI if underlying data supports notifications (by implementing interfaces mentioned above).

Comment: This is working and changes made to the `TestName` property of the underlying object updates fines. However, changing the `Priority` property, of which the list is sorted on, does not cause automatic re-sorting of the list. Maybe this isn't possible anyway.

Comment: It does not make sense to resort on every property change. Because a) after modifying property in ui modified row might instantly move somewhere which kills usability, b) constant sorting affects performance. If you absolutely need to resort on property changes - you can simply subscribe to `PropertyChanged` event of your items and call `cvs.View.Refresh()` in the event handler.

Comment: I should have mentioned - there will be no ability for the user to change the sort order. This functionality is so that failed tests can be moved to the top by the program. Maybe the ListBox isn't ultimately the best tool for this job.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are using `List<T>` instead of `ObservableCollection<T>` as `underlying source collection` for your `CollectionViewSource`.

`ICollectionView` will give you the ability to `filter, sort, or group` the collection along with propagating `INotifyCollectionChanged` events if the underlying collection implements it.

Moreover in case you want to `refresh` your collection when any `property change` in `T` class you have to manually call `Refresh` of your collection OR can use `ICollectionViewLiveShaping` introduced in **.Net4.5**.

Refer to my answer here for both approaches - [Automatically Refresh ICollectionView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17735994/automatically-refresh-icollectionview-filter/17906474#17906474)