# WPF filtering viewed listbox items

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

Im working on simple wpf gallery that loads images from a folder. Each image's filename is also it's ID. My goal is to view, for example, photos number 2 and 3. Here's what i did so far:
XAML containing Listbox

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="257" Margin="46,25,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Grid.Column="1">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Rows="3" Columns="3"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>

        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding}"  Width="120" Margin="1"  MouseLeftButtonDown="leftClickHandler"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Setting sources for images

```
public MainWindow() { 

        InitializeComponent();
        descriptionModel = new DescriptionModel();


        listBox.ItemsSource = Directory.EnumerateFiles(pathPhoto, "*.jpg");


    }
```

I was trying to use CollectionViewSource, but im not sure how to use it properly. I tried adding something like that:

```
ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(listBox.Items);
        view.Filter = (o) => { return listBox.Items.GetItemAt(1); };
```

But im getting error "Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"
Could anyone explain what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The filter works based on the bool (true or false), which is returned by your lambda function.

But here in this case,  your lambda function returns an object which can not be converted to bool (true or false).

You need to change your lambda to return a bool, something like below

use `Contains` of `Items`, which returns bool.

```
ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(listBox.Items);
view.Filter = obj => { return listBox.Items.Contains(photo2_Object); };
```

or

```
view.Filter = obj => { return listBox.Items.Contains(photo3_Object); };
```

or

you can add all the logic you want, but finally return bool (true or false) from lambda.

Comment: That fixed the error i was getting but still doesnt really change my view. It seems that it's switching from showing all (if the lambda returns true) or not showing anything at all (if lambda returns false). Could you explain this part further?

Comment: Sorry @ferals , I missed this comment. Look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17735994/automatically-refresh-icollectionview-filter

Comment: Look into the accepted answer. It has the explanation about, how to refresh. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17735994/automatically-refresh-icollectionview-filter