# How to listen changes in Observable collection in WPF?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, observablecollection

I have user control in which I have placed a Listview and Richtext box control.

ListView is binded to my custom collection.

Below the listview I placed a richtext box in which I want to display my custom text. The custom text is created from the custom collection.

I want to recreate the custom text whenever any thing change in my custom collection.

How can I acheive this. I have implemented INotifyProperty changed event in my Viewmodel.

In the viewmodel, my custom collection resides.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ObservableCollection that also monitors changes on the elements in collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/269073/observablecollection-that-also-monitors-changes-on-the-elements-in-collection)

Comment: Databind the textbox to a property of your viewmodel. When you recreate your custom text, you post that property change. Are you asking how you do data binding to a vm implementing INotifyPropertyChanged?

Answer (score 5):

Use the `CollectionChanged` property from `ObservableCollection`.