# ObservableCollection of objects containing Lists

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, observablecollection

I am using an ObservableCollection for databinding as ItemsSource for DataGrid. Collection contains complex type objects. One of this type properties is a List of strings.

Just for now I see that when I update this List property from code nothing changes in the UI (the primary binding works fine). So, my question is: is it an expected behaviour? Maybe I should not use List as part of the type, but also use an ObservableCollection?

**Update**

Mode is set to OneWay.

Comment: Jehof is correct, however, you may also need to use a HierarchicalDataTemplate (depending on view).

Comment: Type should expose ICollection or another interface as property, backing field should implement INotifyCollectionChanged, such as ObservableCollection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is expected behaviour. The observable collection only notifies of changes to its own contents - that is add, delete, reorder.

What you are looking at is a change to an element in the observablecollection - if you want to see your changes to the class you put in, your element has to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

So currently: If your list property on you complex object changes you won't see it, however if you change that too to be an observablecollection you could see changes to that collection in a sub-itemscontrol like a combobox - but not if you change the collection object to another one - so if you do not implement INotifyPropertyChanged you should set the collectionproperty before the binding is applied.

Comment: That's just what I've done an hour earlier - ObservableCollection instead of List + INotifyPropertyObject on the whole structure (shame on me, I should have thought of it earlier). I mark you answer as a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use a collection, instead of List, that implementes the interface [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx) (like [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx)). Then changes to the collection get populated to the ui.

Answer (score 0):

When you are  updateding your list u have to call INotifyPropertyChange other wise UI wont get update the list result..

INotifyPropertyChange  is the  indication that here some changes occurred in the items source so update it.

Comment: Won't help, since comparison with old value will be the same. Also the external collection did not change - no need to update its view (performance) inner collection is the one that must implement **INotifyCollectionChanged**.

Comment: @Dammy: INotifyCollectionChanged will work no doubt.. But i worked with property using INotifyCollectionChanged  for binding it works for me. The way i knew i told..

Answer (score 0):

This might help as well:

[ObservableCollection that also monitors changes on the elements in collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269073/observablecollection-that-also-monitors-changes-on-the-elements-in-collection)