# ItemsControl Doesn't Resort or Refilter After Page First Loaded

Tags: windows-phone-7, sorting, filter, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

I'm creating an application with a weather map that shows the heat as a Pushpin at different places.  To do this, supplied by own `PushpinModel` that supports the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface:

```
public class PushpinModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region // events
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        #endregion events

        #region // fields
        Heat heat = Heat.normal;
        #endregion fields

        #region // properties
        public string Placename { get; set; }
        public GeoCoordinate Location { get; set; }
        public Heat Heat 
        {
            get { return heat; }
            set
            {
                if (heat != value)
                {
                    heat = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Heat"); 
                }
            }
        }
        public string IDno { get; set; }
        #endregion  properties

        #region // handlers
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propChanged)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propChanged));
        }
        #endregion  handlers
    }
```

The `PushpinModel` objects are contained in an `ObservableCollection` called Pushpins which are periodically updated to ShowWeather:

```
public class Pushpins: ObservableCollection<PushpinModel>
    {

        #region // METHODS
        public void ShowWeather( WeatherReport fromWeatherReport)
        {
            foreach (WeatherRecord w in fromWeatherReport.WeatherRecords)
            {
                    this.First<PushpinModel>(p => p.IDno == w.PlaceID).Heat = w.Heat;
            }
        }
        #endregion methods
    }
```

I display the Pushpins on a Bing Map, but also as items in an ItemsControl:

```
 <ItemsControl x:Name="ItemList" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource placesSortedAndFiltered}}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Border>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Placename}" />
                                </Border>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
```

The ItemsSource is defined as a CollectionViewSource:

```
<CollectionViewSource  x:Key="placesSortedAndFiltered" Source="{Binding ElementName=MyMainPage, Path=Pushpins}" Filter="PlaceHeat_Filter">
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <componentmodel:SortDescription PropertyName="Placename" Direction="Ascending" />
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

with a Filter in the codebehind defined as:

```
 private void PlaceHeat_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Accepted = (((PushpinModel)e.Item).Heat != Heat.na);

        }
```

where a public enum Heat {na,cool,normal,warm,hot}

The problem is that ItemsControl list display appropriately sorted and filtered on page load, but does NOT update when the PushpinModel objects properties are changed.  Please note that when the Pushpins object is bound to a Bing Map Control, the PushpinModel objects do update as expected.  So somehow, my ItemsControl list isn't updating even though it is bound via a CollectionView to an ObservableCollection

Comment: Which properties are you changing? Only your Heat property invokes the PropertyChanged event, the others don't.

Comment: For this example, I'm only changing the Heat property -- and expected it to sort and filter based on that Property.

Comment: For this example, I'm only changing the Heat property of a PushpinModel object -- and expected the ItemsControl whose ItemsSource is the CollectionViewSource placesSortedAndFiltered to sort and filter in response to the change of the Heat property .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the `CollectionViewSource` implementation only supports automatic filtering when the underlying collection is changed (or reset). The filter does not get invoked if a property of an underlying data item changes.

You could either call `Refresh()` on the `CollectionViewSource` when a property for an item in the collection changes, or you could implement your own `CollectionViewSource` which listens to property changed events on underlying data objects, or you could bind directly to a filtered (and sorted) collection rather than using the `CollectionViewSource`.

Comment: Yes.  `INotifyPropertyChanged` does **not** "cascade" on an `ObservableCollection` to become a collection change notification.  You *could* create an implementation of `ObservableCollection` that requires all of its items to implement `INotifyPropertyChange` and the collection itself could cause property changes to become collection changes...

Comment: I assume that your suggesting that I subclass ObservableCollection. Could you sketch how I'd make the property changes into collection changes? Thanks.

Comment: DevDigital.  I don't see that CollectionViewSource has a Refresh method.  How would I call it?

Comment: You need to get the collection view from the collection view source. See http://wpftutorial.net/DataViews.html for details.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help.  Yes, between your answers and those elsewhere on the site. I solve the problem, by creating subclassing the ObservableCollection with the subclass monitoring property changes in the objects it  contains.  The specific implementation can be found on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/269073/observablecollection-that-also-monitors-changes-on-the-elements-in-collection.