# updating observable collection in windows phone 7 application

Tags: windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce

am developing a windows phone which contains database.I've a list box which binds observable collection to display the data retrieved from database. I am able to add and delete rows without any problem.After add or delete, listbox gets updated. But when i update a particular column, updating is working fine in database but in the display page i.e in listbox updated value is not reflected. To see the changes in database i need to relaunch the application.

Can any one tell me how to bind listbox at run time.

Comment: In addition to INotifyPropertyChanged, you'll need to use a 'true' ObservableCollection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/269073/observablecollection-that-also-monitors-changes-on-the-elements-in-collection

Answer (score 0):

To reflect the changes of the properties, you need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in your data model class.
So whenever the value of a property is changed you call the `NotifyPropertyChanged()` function, which will tell the **binded UI Element** to update its value.

Answer (score 0):

The `ObservableCollection` just ensures that the binded listbox gets updated when an item gets added or deleted from it.

In order to see changes in a particular item, the item class must implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface!