# Why does my DataGrid populate only after scrolling in and out of view?

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a WPF DataGrid to whose ItemsSource is bound to an ObservableCollection>.

Tuple is a simple class I made that stores 4 strings in an array. Here is a generic version:

```
public class Tuple<T>: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int _size = 0;

        public Tuple(int size)
        {
            this._size = size;
            _objs = new T[_size];
        }

        private T[] _objs;

        public T this[int i]
        {
            get
            {
                return _objs[i];
            }
            set
            {
                _objs[i] = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(".[" + i + "]");
            }
        }

        public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

At compile time I know I will have 4 columns and so I bind them to an index of the Tuple. At runtime, Tuples are added to the ObservableCollection and also modified. However, I am running into a problem where my DataGrid only updates when the Tuple is created... That is I get output that looks like this:

[image]

The data is present in the ObservableCollection, as if you scroll the DataGrid in and out of view, the text inside the cells appears:

[image]

Any tips?

Comment: If its a different dataset, how do you know those blank spaces aren't suppose to be there?

Comment: @Bob. updated it to reflect changing the same dataset. Also, I confirmed it using a Watch on my collection and breaking during runtime

Comment: ObservableCollection.CollectionChanged event doesn't get triggered when an object inside changes, only when _itself_ changes. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10286028/1466627).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Tuple` only updates when it's created as you don't notify that certain index changed but whole [indexer property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.indexername.aspx) has changed:

```
public T this[int i]
{
   get { return _objs[i]; }
   set
   {
       _objs[i] = value;
       OnPropertyChanged(Binding.IndexerName);
   }
}
```

as for the second part where text appears when it comes back into view it's due to [`VirtualizingStackPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.isvirtualizing.aspx) which by default is `true` and means that items currently not in the view are not rendered and their bindings are not evaluated until they are in the view again

Comment: First, this is great. By making the change to the OnPropertyChanged my datagrid updates properly. Am I understanding this correctly: Binding.IndexerName is a string representing the index in my tuple that changed. This string is received by the ObservableCollection's handler which then alerts the DataGrid?

Comment: It's just a const string. Since indexer property doesn't have real name Binding class exposes this const so that you can notify binding that something in the indexer has changed

Comment: Oh, so it says something like, "some Index of this object has changed" as opposed to: "Index n of this object has changed"?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what it does