# Shaping ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, viewmodel, observablecollection

I have a really simple question.

I got an ObservableCollection of some ViewModel (with INotifyPropertyChanged) which gets updated frequently.

Now I need to shape the data into a new ObservableCollection of NewViewModel like this;

```
        var query = from o in _orders
                select new ComplexRowViewModel()
                           {Isin = o.Isin,
                            Name = o.Isin,
                            GermanSymbol = o.Exchange,
                            PrimarySymbol = o.State.ToString()};
        GridData = query;
```

But of course it doesn't work. Just if I use Obtics or CLINQ, the new collection gets updated if a new item comes into the first collection but if an existing item's properties change, it doesn't get updated in the new collection.

So any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement `INotifyPropertyChange` from `NewViewModel` too. In each of this subscibe the INotifyPropertychange on the source order and raise a new event properly.

Comment: That you should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the objects inside the `ObservableCollection`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Obtics or CLINQ but it sounds like the normal behaviour of the ObservableCollection. It's **not** reacting on property changes of the single items it contains at all. So you have to write your own implementation of the ObservableCollection.
One example is shown here: [ObservableCollection that also monitors changes on the elements in collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269073/observablecollection-that-also-monitors-changes-on-the-elements-in-collection)

Comment: Even if I use the alternative in the link, it still doesn't work with my query. I always got a list.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try my [ObservableComputations](https://github.com/IgorBuchelnikov/ObservableComputations) library. Using that library:

```C#
        var query = _orders.Selecting(o => 
                new ComplexRowViewModel()
                           {Isin = o.Isin,
                            Name = o.Isin,
                            GermanSymbol = o.Exchange,
                            PrimarySymbol = o.State.ToString()};
        GridData = query;
```

To make code above working _orders should be of type `ObservableCollection` and `Order` class (I suggest it is type of elements in _orders `ObservableCollection`) should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.