# how to bind a property that can change in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, inotifypropertychanged

I have a table that stores data received from an external Internet resource. When changing a table cell, I need to send new data to the server. The question is how to correctly bind the property that will store the new data?

The View DataGrid XAML:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="2"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Properties, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  IsReadOnly="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=name}"
                                     IsReadOnly="False"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Value">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=value}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

And View Model Property of collection that places in DataGrid:

```
private ObservableCollection<IProperties> _Properties;
public ObservableCollection<IProperties> Properties
    {
        get => _Properties;
        set
        {
            _Properties = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Properties));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possible ways to do that:

1. In your concrete implementation of the `IProperty` interface, put your code in the setter of your `value` property.
2. Alternatively, you can make your `IProperty` implementation also implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and subscribe to the PropertyChanged event of *all* items in your ObservableCollection. Take care to attach and de-attach event handlers as you add or remove items from the collection.
3. Instead of doing the steps in option 2 manually, you can use a [special kind of ObservableCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/269073/87698) for that purpose. Or use a [`BindingList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.bindinglist-1.listchanged?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-7.0) instead, which already covers this use case and raises the `ListChanged` event whenever one of its items raises its `PropertyChanged` event.